# If sizeof(long) is 4 bytes on my machine, can I infer that sizeof(long long) will be 8 bytes?

Tags: c, long-integer, sizeof

```
printf("Size of long int: %zu\n" , sizeof(long));
printf("Size of long long int: %zu\n" , sizeof(long long));
```

When run on my 64bit machine the output is:

```
Size of long int: 8
Size of long long int: 8
```

Comment: No. If `CHAR_BIT` from `<limits.h>` is greater than `8` (for example, `CHAR_BIT == 16`), a conforming implementation may have `sizeof(long) == 4` and `sizeof(long long) == 4` both.

Comment: No.  The only guarantee is that `sizeof(long long) >= sizeof(long)`.   Note the potential for equality.

Comment: @Peter Well, there is another guarantee, namely that `long long` can represent all values between (-(2 to the power of 63) + 1) and ((2 to the power of 63) - 1), which implies at least 64 bits of width.

Comment: Have a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models

Comment: @EOF -  The question is about the size of the types, not the range of values they can represent.

Comment: the size of the next type isn't necessarily twice the previous one. For example there are platforms with [4-byte int and 5-byte long](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28352310/995714)

Answer (score 3):

It ***depends***.

Standard-wise, in general you cannot imply anything about the size of a type from the size of another type, if not a lower bound (depending on the value of `CHAR_BIT`). See below for a more detailed answer.

Implementation-wise, if the compiler is standard-compliant and the value of `CHAR_BIT` is `8` (which is the most common thing to have), then `sizeof long` would need to be *at least* `4`, and `sizeof long long` would need to be *at least* `8`. Leaving out esoteric architectures, in which strange padding bits appear (like for example the [Itanium processor](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150727-00/?p=90821) with its "Not a Thing" reserved bit), it makes sense to assume `sizeof long long` to be `8` under those circumstances.

In the case of GCC for Intel x86 and ARM for example, AFAIK this assumption holds true, so the answer to your question would be "yes". However, I would strongly advise to not make any design choice based on such a simple assumption that can be easily tested at compile time, like this:

---

Standard-wise, more precisely: the C standard does not dictate any rule as to what the size of an integer type should exactly be. It only defines a minimum *range of values* that the type should be capable of representing. For C99 those values are specified in ISO/IEC 9088:1999 §5.2.4.2 "Numerical limits" ([page 21 here](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)).

The only *implicit* requirement on the size of signed integer types is in §6.2.6.2 "Integer types":

> 1. For unsigned  integer  types  other  than unsigned  char, the  bits  of  the  object representation  shall  be  divided  into  two groups:  value  bits  and  padding  bits  (there  need not  be  any of the  latter). If  there  are N value  bits,  each  bit  shall  represent  a  different power  of  2  between  1  and  2^(N−1), so that  objects  of  that  type  shall  be  capable  of representing  values  from  0  to  2^(N−1) using  a  pure  binary  representation;  this  shall  be known as the value representation. The values of any padding bits are unspecified.
> 2. For signed  integer  types,  the  bits  of  the  object  representation  shall  be  divided  into  three groups:  value  bits,  padding  bits,  and  the  sign  bit. There  need  not  be  any padding  bits; there shall be exactly one sign bit. Each bit that is a value bit shall have the same value as the same bit in the object representation of the corresponding unsigned type (if there are M value bits in the signed type and N in the unsigned type, then M ≤ N).

The first point implicitly poses a lower bound for the number of bits of an integer type: since the standard defines the minimum ranges of values those types should be capable of representing, and also states that there should be exactly N bits for such value, we know that each integer type should be *at least* N bits of size to be able to represent values from 0 to 2^(N-1).

However, given the presence of "padding bits", there is *no guarantee* on an upper bound for the size of integer types. Therefore, in general, not only there is *no guarantee* that `sizeof long == 4` implies `sizeof long long == 8`, but there also is *no guarantee* that `sizeof long long >= sizeof long` in the first place. This also applies to other integer types.

For what concerns the standard, a compliant implementation could even have:

- `CHAR_BIT == 8`
- `sizeof int == 10`, with 31 bits for value, 1 for sign and 47 for padding
- `sizeof long == 8`, with 63 bits for value, 1 for sign and 0 for padding.

Comment: This answer is unhelpful. While the perverse padding it describes is technically permissible in the C standard, it does not occur in any practical C implementation. It is perfectly fine to discuss technicalities, but, if an answer is to be helpful, it ought to discuss assumptions that are reasonable for practical situations, discuss ways to deal with the absurd technically possible situations if truly desired, and discuss the rankings and partial orderings of precisions that are required by the standard. (Incidentally, 31 value 1, 1 sign bit, and 47 padding bits do not give 10 8-bit bytes.)

Comment: I remember at least one i386 compiler ([lcc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LCC_(compiler))) where  bytes were (of course) 8 bit and both `sizeof(long) == 4` and `sizeof(long long) == 4`. Admittedly, that was long time ago, but I simply cannot see why the "for sure" from your 2nd paragraph is that sure at all.

Comment: @mosvy if the compiler is conforming to the standard, then having `CHAR_BIT == 8` means that `sizeof long` must be `>= 4` to represent the range of values described by the standard, and therefore `sizeof long long` must be `>=8` for the same reason.

Comment: You should make that clear in your answer. And you probably mean `sizeof (long long) >= sizeof (long)`, not the reverse.